# Sound through UIButton does not work, swift

Tags: swift

I have 4 buttons that trigger 4 different sounds. All buttons work, I have a println button 1, button2, etc.. For some reason I am only hearing sounds that come through button 3 and 4. I used the same coding method for all buttons and audio players, So I have no idea what the problem could be. This is my code.

There are no errors or anything and again all buttons and audio players work the same, so I'm not sure why button 1 and 2 don't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class MusicPlayer {

var onePlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
var twoPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
var threePlayer : AVAudioPlayer?
var fourPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?


func playOneSound() {
    twoPlayer!.play()
}

func playTwoSound() {

    twoPlayer!.play()
}

func playThreeSound() {

    threePlayer!.play()
}

func playFourSound() {

    fourPlayer!.play()
}

func stopOneSound() {
    twoPlayer!.stop()
}

func stopTwoSound() {

    twoPlayer!.stop()
}

func stopThreeSound() {

    threePlayer!.stop()
}

func stopFourSound() {

    fourPlayer!.stop()
}

class var sharedInstance: MusicPlayer {
    struct Static {
        static var instance: MusicPlayer?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = MusicPlayer()
    }

    return Static.instance!
}

init() {


    // Create an NSURL for the correct file
    let oneSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Go To Sleep 1", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let twoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Go To Sleep 2", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let threeSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Go To Sleep 3", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let fourSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Go To Sleep 5", ofType: "mp3")!)

    // Create a new AVAudioPlayer with the correct file
    onePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: oneSound, error: nil)
    twoPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: twoSound, error: nil)
    threePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: threeSound, error: nil)
    fourPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fourSound, error: nil)

    /*onePlayer!.volume = masterEffectSoundLevel
    twoPlayer!.volume = masterEffectSoundLevel
    threePlayer!.volume = masterEffectSoundLevel
    fourPlayer!.volume = masterEffectSoundLevel*/


    // Prepare for playback, set loop count to infinite, start playback
    onePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    twoPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    threePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    fourPlayer!.prepareToPlay()

}
```

This is my code for the buttons :

```
 @IBAction func settingOneButton(sender: UIButton) {
    settingOne.hidden = false
    settingTwo.hidden = true
    settingThree.hidden = true
    settingFour.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func settingTwoButton(sender: UIButton) {
    settingOne.hidden = true
    settingTwo.hidden = false
    settingThree.hidden = true
    settingFour.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func settingThreeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    settingOne.hidden = true
    settingTwo.hidden = true
    settingThree.hidden = false
    settingFour.hidden = true

}

@IBAction func settingFourButton(sender: UIButton) {
    settingOne.hidden = true
    settingTwo.hidden = true
    settingThree.hidden = true
    settingFour.hidden = false

}

@IBAction func goToSleepPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if settingOne.hidden == false {

        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.playOneSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopTwoSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopThreeSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopFourSound()
        println("one")

    } else if settingTwo.hidden == false {
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.playTwoSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopOneSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopThreeSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopFourSound()
        println("two")

    } else if settingThree.hidden == false {

        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.playThreeSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopOneSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopTwoSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopFourSound()
        println("three")

    } else if settingFour.hidden == false {
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.playFourSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopOneSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopTwoSound()
        MusicPlayer.sharedInstance.stopThreeSound()
        println("four")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had twoPlayer both in playOneSound() and playTwoSound().